# In a 50 Hz system a capacitor is connected to 11kv AC bus

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

there is 50 kvar being supplied to the load. Find the capacitance.

In a recent Electrical exam I got this problem, but wasn't able to answer it. Can anybody give me a clue on how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You have to do your part by learning some basics.  Once you do, you'll realize that "50 Hz capacitor" is just gibberish.  What is "kvar"?  Perhaps you mean "kVA"?  What is supplying this "50 kvar", the bus, the capacitor, something else.  This level of sloppiness has no place in engineering.

Comment: It seems from user28258's answer that this question is not as unanswerable as those *unfamiliar* with this sub-discipline of Electrical Engineering might *mistakenly assume*

Comment: @OlinLathrop - This is not sloppiness, but merely the customary language of an area of Electrical Engineering of which *you are apparently ignorant of the practice* and so must decide if you wish to address the question from first principles, *or, as would often be wiser for you, leave it to others*.  "kvar" may be a mystery *to you* but it **was not** to those with **expertise in this area**.

Comment: @Chris: You still don't get it. Of course I know what kVA or kVAr is, but that's not what the OP wrote. Once again in your eagerness to find fault with the person pointing out the sloppiness instead of the one being sloppy, you have again ignored "50 hz capacitor". You still haven't shown me a 50 Hz capacitor, let along a 50 hz capacitor. And then the very poorly worded sentence leaves it ambiguous whether the capacitor or the bus is supposed to be doing the supplying. The fact that it is possible to probably infer the intended meaning is irrelevant.

Comment: A "50 Hz" capacitor, much like a "terminating resistor" is a component named for it's *role*.  Actual *practice* is full of such conventions, which specify the important application information from which other details (such as the value in farads or ohms) can be calculated.

Comment: @Chris I have to say, I think there is middle ground here. Typos or incorrectly stated units and concepts are *confusing* and make an already difficult topic less clear. I agree with Olin that lazy or just plain incorrect data has no place in engineering. On the other hand, Olin you could try to leave comments to the OP like "You said *x* but did you really mean *y*?" If the OP improves or clarifies the question then everyone wins. If not, *then* I say call them out on their sloppiness.

Comment: @rawbrawb: You edited the question but you still kept "kvar", didn't capitalize the first letter of the first sentence, left important information in the title only, left "can anybody", and left "thanks" at the end. In any case, the OP should have been the one to edit the question. Doing it for him only teaches that sloppiness gets rewarded. Shame on you.  Folks, preciseness and attention to detail matter in engineering.  Sloppy expression is a symptom of sloppy thinking, and sloppy thinkers are a waste of time in engineering, thereofore pointless to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question right, then 50Hz and 11kV represent the AC-power source, 50kVAr is reactive power on unknown capactior and numias's job on the exam was to find the capacitance of this unknown capactior.

If you read the wiki on AC power, you would know that reactance for ideal capactior is: 
$$
X = 1/\omega C
$$

If you put that in equation for power, you will get:
$$Q = U^2/X = U^2\omega C$$

Therefore:
$$C=Q/U^2\omega$$
Now all you have to do is put in the numbers and I also suggest you to read wiki on this topic.

Comment: That's very easy actually. Damn, I failed to do it.

Comment: While this is a fine answer, it's too bad the *personal vendettas* have suppressed the first applicable answer that was posted.  A technical site should be about *what is being said* and not about *who is saying it*.

Comment: @Chris: There is a history with the particular user you are referring to.  In this case he did write a lucid and reasonable answer, but usually that's not the case.  The real point though is that he's on suspension and shouldn't be here.  This the same as our society not tolerating prisoners escaping from jail just because sometimes they don't do bad things when they are out.

Comment: When "lucid and reasonable" technical information must be suppressed because of its apparent authorship, we've really, really lost our way.  The whole point of technical fields is that we are supposed to care about the facts, not the speaker.

Comment: @Chris: So you don't mind when inmates escape from your local jail that nobody tries to collect them unless they do bad things again?  If so, make sure they only hang around in front of your house.  I don't want them in my town.

Comment: If an escaped inmate contributes time landscaping the local garden, I'm not going to advocate plowing it under when it's discovered who did the work!